# Problems with invoking a script as another user within user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

Currently, I have the following script loaded in the user data.

```
$username = "ABC"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -String "xxx" -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $Password
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Credential $credential -WorkingDirectory "C:\Test" -ArgumentList @(".\script.ps1") -Wait
```

However, it seems that the script.ps1 is not being executed. There are no errors or outputs. It just doesn't work. The script only works when it is executed in the instance itself and not when during instance launch and the user data is invoked.

Update:
The purpose of the script.ps1 is to return a text file that shows what user has executed the script.ps1. So, the intended output after executing the user data would be a text file which is not the case.

Script.ps1

([Environment]::UserDomainName + "" + [Environment]::UserName) | out-file test.txt
"$env:userdomain$env:username" | out-file -append test.txt
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name | out-file -append test.txt

Comment: What makes you think it is not working?  What does script.ps1 do?  Also, since you are setting the working directory to C:\Test that is where script.ps1 should be as '.' will be the working directory.

Comment: Try `Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Credential $credential -WorkingDirectory "C:\Test" -ArgumentList "-NoExit", "-File \`"C:\fullPath\to\script.ps1\`""`. If that didn't work we would need a bit more details as to what do you mean by "not being executed". Also adding the code for `script.ps1` can help us understand what the issue could be.